# Error Resize Imagemagick in Node.JS

Tags: node.js, imagemagick

I have already issued the command for npm to install imagemagick. 
I have installed imagemagick exe on my machine and ran a test of a command to change the image type from jpg to png - and that worked. 
So in node js I have the following code:

```
im.resize({
  srcPath: req.files.recipeImage.filename,
  dstPath: beginName+"-small.jpg",
  width:   256
}, function(err, stdout, stderr){
  if (err) throw err;
});
```

Unfortunately in my project it returns:

```
Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -set
```

I saw on another post and on the imagemagick website that it means the exe was not run, but I have the command line working in my control panel on Windows. Is there another step I am missing to get this to work?

Comment: What is the content of `req.files.recipeImage.filename` and `beginName`

Comment: Sorry Mustafa, I did not see your comment there, I kept looking for answers and missed the comment on my post. Anyway, I am getting back "tc.jpg" the name of my file for the req.files.recipeImage.filename (and I physically put a file next to index.js to make sure it could find it) and beginName is returned as "tc" which is correct too.

Answer (score 0):

See this discussion: [imagemagick with nodejs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703973/imagemagick-with-nodejs-not-working)

You have to install ImageMagick, choose the correct installation file from the site: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)

After restart Windows and you will see all will work.