# Not able to resize image using ImageMagick Node.js

Tags: javascript, node.js, imagemagick

I am trying to resize an image using [ImageMagick](https://github.com/rsms/node-imagemagick) and I've referred [this example](http://code4node.com/snippet/resize-an-image-using-imagemagick)

and I am getting this error:

```
{ [Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -set
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 4, signal: null }
```

Below is my Code:

```
exports.generateThumbnail=function(imageURL,savePath,filename,callback){
    console.log(imageURL);
    console.log(savePath);
    console.log(filename);

    var options = {
       width: 80,
       height: 80,
       srcPath: imageURL,
       dstPath: savePath+"\\thumb_"+filename
    };

    im.resize(options, function(err) {
      if(err) { console.log( err); }
      console.log("Image resize complete");
    });

}
```

This is everything I am getting in my console:

```
fieldNameHere
{ _readableState:
   { highWaterMark: 16384,
     buffer: [],
     length: 0,
     pipes: null,
     pipesCount: 0,
     flowing: false,
     ended: false,
     endEmitted: false,
     reading: false,
     calledRead: false,
     sync: true,
     needReadable: false,
     emittedReadable: false,
     readableListening: false,
     objectMode: false,
     defaultEncoding: 'utf8',
     ranOut: false,
     awaitDrain: 0,
     readingMore: false,
     decoder: null,
     encoding: null },
  readable: true,
  domain: null,
  _events: { end: [Function] },
  _maxListeners: 10,
  truncated: false,
  _read: [Function] }
look.png
7bit
image/png
.\Images\bhuwan\media\look.pnglook.png
.\Images\bhuwan\media
look.png
{ [Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - -set
] timedOut: false, killed: false, code: 4, signal: null }
```

Also, I've tried every possible library on npmjs.org including the most poppular ones like easyimage and node-thumbnail. None of them are working on windows and have issues listed on github.

What am i doing wrong in this.? Please help.!

**EDIT:**

Just in case you need the code in which I am calling the above method:

```
app.post('/uploadImage',function(req,res){
    console.log('Starting to read params');
    var alias=req.query.alias;
    var imagetype=req.query.imagetype;  //can be media/profile
    console.log(alias);
    console.log(imagetype);
    var busboy = new Busboy({ headers: req.headers });
    busboy.on('file', function(fieldname, file, filename, encoding, mimetype) {
        saveTo = ".\\Images\\"+alias+"\\"+imagetype+"\\"+filename;
        saveDirectory= ".\\Images\\"+alias+"\\"+imagetype;
        console.log(fieldname);
        console.log(file);
        console.log(filename); //this is the one
        ImageName=filename;
        console.log(encoding);
        console.log(mimetype);
        imagePathFull=saveTo+filename;
        if (fs.existsSync(saveTo)) {
            file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
        }
        else{
            mkdirp(".\\Images\\"+alias+"\\"+imagetype,function(err){
                 file.pipe(fs.createWriteStream(saveTo));
            });
        }   
    });
    busboy.on('finish', function() {
        imageHandle.generateThumbnail(imagePathFull,saveDirectory,ImageName,function(err){
            if(!err){
                res.writeHead(200, { 'Connection': 'close' });
                res.status(200).end();
            }
            else{
                res.writeHead(500, { 'Connection': 'close' });
                res.status(500).end();
            }
        });

    });
    return req.pipe(busboy);
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I had the same issue and solved it by installing `imagemagik.exe` on Windows as recommended here: [imagemagick with nodejs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703973/imagemagick-with-nodejs-not-working).

Download: [Link](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php#windows)

Hope it helps!