# graphicsMagick on nodejs installed on windows not working, imageMagick throws error

Tags: windows, node.js, image-processing, heroku, graphicsmagick

I am running graphicsMagick along with node on windows. I want to resize image and reduce quality. Below is my code. Unforutnately the image is neither resized nor reduced in Quality although I dont have any error. Below is my code.

```
var gm = require('gm'), 
graphicsMagick = gm.subClass({imageMagick: true});
 //resizing image with graphicsMagick and storing in the same path
                graphicsMagick(fullPathFileName)
                    .resize(null, 150)
                    .noProfile()
                    .quality(70)
                    .write(fullPathFileName, function (err) {
                        if (!err) console.log('Image resized');
                    });
```

Further imageMagick is installed.
Although, I should agree that when I used imageMagick directly in node by requiring image magic, I got the error described in link [imagemagick with nodejs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703973/imagemagick-with-nodejs-not-working) so instead of imageMagick I required graphicsMagick, now there is no error but nothing happening on file too.

code that generated error while requiring imageMagick was -->

```
var im = require('imagemagick');
im.resize({ 
         srcPath: fullPathFileName, 
         dstPath: fullPathFileName, 
          height: 150, 
         quality: 0.8, 
         format: 'png' }, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
              if (err) throw err; 
           console.log('resized image to fit 150px height'); 
       });
```

I uploaded the app to heroku and still graphicsMagick doesn't resize image and no errors, what's happening?

Regards,
Chidan

Comment: Your code is telling `gm` to use `imageMagick`. Do you have ImageMagick installed?

Comment: For sure yes and thats why I am not getting any error.

Comment: Although, I should agree that when I used imageMagick directly in node by requiring image magic, I got the error described in link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703973/imagemagick-with-nodejs-not-working. so instead of imageMagick I required graphicsMagick, now there is no error but nothing happening on file too..

Comment: code that generated error while requiring imageMagick was -->  im.resize({
                    srcPath: fullPathFileName,
                    dstPath: fullPathFileName,
                    height: 150,
                    quality: 0.8,
                    format: 'png'
                }, function (err, stdout, stderr) {
                    if (err) throw err;
                    console.log('resized image to fit 150px height');
                });

Comment: you should be able to edit your original question to add the code that's generating the error so that people see this important info on first-read.