# Node.js & GM library

Tags: node.js

I'm working on a **Node.js** application and I'm facing a critical problem right now which it is Resizing img after uploading .. the thing is everything goes right starting from uploading to getting the path of the uploaded img but ***I can't understand why this is happening*** .. here's my code and the error

```
  var fileName = req.file.filename;
  var filpath = "/uploads/" + fileName;

  gm(filpath)
  .resize(240, 240)
  .write('/uploads/'+'resized-'+fileName, function (err) {
    if (err) console.log(err);
    else console.log("HOOLA");
  });
```

The error is

```
{ [Error: Command failed: Invalid Parameter - /uploaded_file-1474832730810.png
] code: 4, signal: null }
```

The log
[image]

**UPDATE:**
first of all I would like to thank @r-a-lucas,and here's the full answer for Windows users:

1. npm install gm --save
2. download the latest ImageMagick from here [ImageMagic EXE](https://www.imagemagick.org/script/download.php)
3. Make sure it is excusable (advance system settings -> Advance -> Environment Variables -> add Path most likely in C:\Program Files\ImageMagick-*** )
4. In your JS file make sure to add (__dirname) to get the full path of the img. `gm(__dirname+filpath)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like you may need to install imagemagick for Windows.  Check out this answer here: [imagemagick with nodejs not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11703973/imagemagick-with-nodejs-not-working).  Hopefully that helps.  Best.

Comment: already installed `ABC@DESKTOP-VKM06U6 MINGW32 ~/Desktop/Node.js/sales app
$ npm install ImageMagick --save
imagemagick@0.1.3 node_modules\imagemagick`

Comment: Yes, this is beyond doing just the `npm install` but that you may need to install the imagemagick.exe and make sure that the executable is in the path.

Comment: definitely you are right .. can't thank you enough bro .. gonna update the full answer now :D

Comment: Take care that another convert.exe can be under C:\Windows\System32\convert.exe. I have it on my Windows 10, and it is the selected one from the PATH.