# Error EOF when trying to resize images using Gulp on Windows

Tags: windows, npm, gulp, imagemagick, image-manipulation

I get an error as follows when calling `resize:images` task in my gulpfile (see bottom) ...

```
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^
Error: Error: write EOF
    at finish (C:\Users\brendan\Documents\Code\Web\TheOrm\WWW\v3\node_modules\gulp-gm\index.js:40:21)
    at gm.<anonymous> (C:\Users\brendan\Documents\Code\Web\TheOrm\WWW\v3\node_modules\async\lib\async.js:485:30)
    at emitMany (events.js:127:13)
    at gm.emit (events.js:201:7)
    at gm.<anonymous> (C:\Users\brendan\Documents\Code\Web\TheOrm\WWW\v3\node_modules\gm\lib\getters.js:70:16)
    at Socket.cb (C:\Users\brendan\Documents\Code\Web\TheOrm\WWW\v3\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:322:16)
    at Socket.g (events.js:291:16)
    at emitOne (events.js:96:13)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:188:7)
    at onwriteError (_stream_writable.js:340:10)
```

Imagemagick is installed and seems to work from the command line. i.e. `magick -help` gives sensible output and you can save the inbuilt test logo image.

I have tried various other gulp libraries including `gulp-responsive-images` which gives an empty pipe error.

I tried this under the Linux Subsystem for Windows and it works fine - it seems that this is a Windows only problem.

After forking `gulp-image-resize` and running the test suite I get the following error ...

```
...
[14:18:20] Starting 'image_resize:interlace_and_resize_imagemagick'...
events.js:160
      throw er; // Unhandled 'error' event
      ^

Error: write EPIPE
    at exports._errnoException (util.js:1026:11)
    at Socket._writeGeneric (net.js:710:26)
    at Socket._write (net.js:729:8)
    at doWrite (_stream_writable.js:328:12)
    at writeOrBuffer (_stream_writable.js:314:5)
    at Socket.Writable.write (_stream_writable.js:241:11)
    at Socket.write (net.js:656:40)
    at gm._spawn (C:\Users\brendan\Documents\Code\OpenSource\gulp-image-resize\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:194:18)
    at gm._exec (C:\Users\brendan\Documents\Code\OpenSource\gulp-image-resize\node_modules\gm\lib\command.js:167:17)
    at gm.proto.(anonymous function) [as size] (C:\Users\brendan\Documents\Code\OpenSource\gulp-image-resize\node_modules\gm\lib\getters.js:68:12)
```

Unfortunately, the repo had bug reporting disabled - does anyone know how this might be remedied?

Here is my gulpfile.js ...

```
let gulp = require('gulp');
let imageResize = require('gulp-image-resize');
let path = require('path');
let rename = require('gulp-rename');
let debug = require('gulp-debug');

let INPUT_DIR = './NO_UPLOAD/img_src';
let OUTPUT_DIR = './NO_UPLOAD/img_tmp';

gulp.task('resize:images', function() {
    relFns = [
        'logo.png',
        'image.png',
        ].map((f) => path.join(INPUT_DIR, f));
    return gulp.src(relFns, { base: INPUT_DIR })
        .pipe(debug({ title: 'resized' }))
        .pipe(imageResize({
            width: 100
        }))
        .pipe(rename((path) => { path.basename += '.sml'  }))
        .pipe(gulp.dest(OUTPUT_DIR));
});
```

Answer (score 10):

There were a number of issues ...

1. Make sure [Graphicsmagick](http://www.graphicsmagick.org/) is installed as well (may not be necessary but did not do any harm to install)
2. make sure both `gm` and `magick` are in your path
3. After referring to a comment on [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11710210/199), I found restarting the computer fixed the issue. (I was surprised at the restart since opening up a new console usually works.)
4. Finally **make sure that you don't run from a console opened from Visual Studio Code instance**. VSCode is a 32bit app and launches a 32bit console which does not run 64bit versions of Imagemagick. Instead launch the console from Explorer.

Comment: Good point!

But it seems to access `convert.exe` which is also part of Windows NT file system converter. Set the magick path before `C:\Windows\system32` like:

`PATH c:\Program Files (x86)\ImageMagick-6.7.6-Q8;%PATH%`

Comment: I was running gulp from VSCode! Executing from Powershell solved the issue